# find: regular expression in name

Tags: find, gnu

suppose I write:

```
find . -regex "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(foo|bar).csv.gz" -printf "%f\n"
```

This command looks to me like it should work.  I have iterated through the various regextype options and various regex formats, but am unable to get this sort of regex to work through find.  Is there something simple I am getting wrong here regarding find and the regular expression parser?

Comment: As far as I know `-name` does not take regular expressions. You should use `-regex` or `-iregex` for that. See manuals for find: https://linux.die.net/man/1/find.

Comment: @meuh and the same applies for regex, just iterated though

Comment: The comment appeared while I was writing mine. I'm happy to delete mine if you'd rather post your own, @steeldriver.

Comment: @terdon no problem, already upvoted it ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Find's `-name` doesn't take regular expressions (this was used in the original version of the question). It takes shell globs, and that isn't a valid shell glob. You want to use the `-regex` test, but also need to tell it to use extended regular expressions or any other flavor that understands the `{N}` and `foo|bar` notations. Finally, unlike `-name`, the `-regex` test looks at the entire pathname, so you need something like this:

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(foo|bar).csv.gz" -printf "%f\n"
5678-34-56-bar.csv.gz
1234-12-12-foo.csv.gz
```

If you want to use `-name`, you could do:

```
find . \( \
       -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-foo.csv.gz" \
    -o -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-bar.csv.gz" \
       \) -printf "%f\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the `fd` tool:

```bsh
fd '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(foo|bar).csv.gz'
```

https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

Answer (score 2):

If you have reasonable filenames (at least in this folder) you could run something along the lines of

```
 find . | grep -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(foo|bar).csv.gz'
```

This way you can benefit from the a variety of grep options.

Comment: Even for non-reasonable ones, actually: `find . -print0 | grep -z -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-(foo|bar).csv.gz' | tr '\0' '\n'`. That will replace the nulls with newlines so the output might be a little hard to parse, but at least it can deal with any file name.